# Cannot create index with automated generated entity from DB org.hibernate.AnnotationException: Unable to create index

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, jakarta-ee

I'm trying to deploy an EAR application (includes ejb and war modules). The problem is it cannot create indexes of a foreign key in associative entity (WorkerHasRole). Every entity with relationships was created automatically in IntelliJ. I am running it on Wildfly 25.0.0. I can't figure it out even with help of the internet...

Database diagram
[database screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wNjSe.png)

Error that occures:

```
03:39:20,912 ERROR [org.jboss.msc.service.fail] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 95) MSC000001: Failed to start service jboss.persistenceunit."officeApplication_ear_exploded/officeApplication.jar#OfficeApplicationDS": org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.persistenceunit."officeApplication_ear_exploded/officeApplication.jar#OfficeApplicationDS": org.hibernate.AnnotationException: Unable to create index (worker_idworker) on table worker_has_role: database column 'worker_idworker' not found. Make sure that you use the correct column name which depends on the naming strategy in use (it may not be the same as the property name in the entity, especially for relational types)
    at org.jboss.as.jpa@25.0.0.Final//org.jboss.as.jpa.service.PersistenceUnitServiceImpl$1$1.run(PersistenceUnitServiceImpl.java:198)
    at org.jboss.as.jpa@25.0.0.Final//org.jboss.as.jpa.service.PersistenceUnitServiceImpl$1$1.run(PersistenceUnitServiceImpl.java:128)
    at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:399)
    at org.wildfly.security.elytron-base@1.17.1.Final//org.wildfly.security.manager.WildFlySecurityManager.doChecked(WildFlySecurityManager.java:664)
    at org.jboss.as.jpa@25.0.0.Final//org.jboss.as.jpa.service.PersistenceUnitServiceImpl$1.run(PersistenceUnitServiceImpl.java:213)
    at org.jboss.threads@2.4.0.Final//org.jboss.threads.ContextClassLoaderSavingRunnable.run(ContextClassLoaderSavingRunnable.java:35)
    at org.jboss.threads@2.4.0.Final//org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor.safeRun(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1990)
    at org.jboss.threads@2.4.0.Final//org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor$ThreadBody.doRunTask(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1486)
    at org.jboss.threads@2.4.0.Final//org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor$ThreadBody.run(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1377)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:833)
    at org.jboss.threads@2.4.0.Final//org.jboss.threads.JBossThread.run(JBossThread.java:513)
Caused by: org.hibernate.AnnotationException: Unable to create index (worker_idworker) on table worker_has_role: database column 'worker_idworker' not found. Make sure that you use the correct column name which depends on the naming strategy in use (it may not be the same as the property name in the entity, especially for relational types)
    at org.hibernate@5.3.23.Final//org.hibernate.boot.internal.InFlightMetadataCollectorImpl.buildUniqueKeyFromColumnNames(InFlightMetadataCollectorImpl.java:2137)
    at org.hibernate@5.3.23.Final//org.hibernate.boot.internal.InFlightMetadataCollectorImpl.processJPAIndexHolders(InFlightMetadataCollectorImpl.java:2149)
    at org.hibernate@5.3.23.Final//org.hibernate.boot.internal.InFlightMetadataCollectorImpl.processSecondPasses(InFlightMetadataCollectorImpl.java:1671)
    at org.hibernate@5.3.23.Final//org.hibernate.boot.model.process.spi.MetadataBuildingProcess.complete(MetadataBuildingProcess.java:287)
    at org.hibernate@5.3.23.Final//org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.metadata(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:1215)
    at org.hibernate@5.3.23.Final//org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.build(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:1246)
    at org.hibernate.jipijapa-hibernate5-3@25.0.0.Final//org.jboss.as.jpa.hibernate5.TwoPhaseBootstrapImpl.build(TwoPhaseBootstrapImpl.java:44)
    at org.jboss.as.jpa@25.0.0.Final//org.jboss.as.jpa.service.PersistenceUnitServiceImpl$1$1.run(PersistenceUnitServiceImpl.java:170)
    ... 10 more

03:39:20,981 INFO  [org.jboss.as.jpa] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 95) WFLYJPA0010: Starting Persistence Unit (phase 2 of 2) Service 'officeApplication_ear_exploded/officeApplication.war#OfficeApplicationPU'
03:39:20,981 INFO  [org.hibernate.dialect.Dialect] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 95) HHH000400: Using dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL55Dialect
03:39:20,983 INFO  [org.hibernate.envers.boot.internal.EnversServiceImpl] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 95) Envers integration enabled? : true
03:39:20,989 ERROR [org.jboss.as.controller.management-operation] (management-handler-thread - 1) WFLYCTL0013: Operation ("deploy") failed - address: ([("deployment" => "officeApplication_ear_exploded")]) - failure description: {"WFLYCTL0080: Failed services" => {"jboss.persistenceunit.\"officeApplication_ear_exploded/officeApplication.jar#OfficeApplicationDS\"" => "org.hibernate.AnnotationException: Unable to create index (worker_idworker) on table worker_has_role: database column 'worker_idworker' not found. Make sure that you use the correct column name which depends on the naming strategy in use (it may not be the same as the property name in the entity, especially for relational types)
    Caused by: org.hibernate.AnnotationException: Unable to create index (worker_idworker) on table worker_has_role: database column 'worker_idworker' not found. Make sure that you use the correct column name which depends on the naming strategy in use (it may not be the same as the property name in the entity, especially for relational types)"}}
03:39:20,990 ERROR [org.jboss.as.controller.management-operation] (management-handler-thread - 1) WFLYCTL0013: Operation ("deploy") failed - address: ([("deployment" => "officeApplication_ear_exploded")]) - failure description: {"WFLYCTL0080: Failed services" => {"jboss.persistenceunit.\"officeApplication_ear_exploded/officeApplication.jar#OfficeApplicationDS\"" => "org.hibernate.AnnotationException: Unable to create index (worker_idworker) on table worker_has_role: database column 'worker_idworker' not found. Make sure that you use the correct column name which depends on the naming strategy in use (it may not be the same as the property name in the entity, especially for relational types)
    Caused by: org.hibernate.AnnotationException: Unable to create index (worker_idworker) on table worker_has_role: database column 'worker_idworker' not found. Make sure that you use the correct column name which depends on the naming strategy in use (it may not be the same as the property name in the entity, especially for relational types)"}}
03:39:20,990 ERROR [org.jboss.as.server] (management-handler-thread - 1) WFLYSRV0021: Deploy of deployment "officeApplication_ear_exploded.ear" was rolled back with the following failure message: 
{"WFLYCTL0080: Failed services" => {"jboss.persistenceunit.\"officeApplication_ear_exploded/officeApplication.jar#OfficeApplicationDS\"" => "org.hibernate.AnnotationException: Unable to create index (worker_idworker) on table worker_has_role: database column 'worker_idworker' not found. Make sure that you use the correct column name which depends on the naming strategy in use (it may not be the same as the property name in the entity, especially for relational types)
    Caused by: org.hibernate.AnnotationException: Unable to create index (worker_idworker) on table worker_has_role: database column 'worker_idworker' not found. Make sure that you use the correct column name which depends on the naming strategy in use (it may not be the same as the property name in the entity, especially for relational types)"}}
03:39:20,990 INFO  [org.jboss.as.jpa] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 95) WFLYJPA0011: Stopping Persistence Unit (phase 1 of 2) Service 'officeApplication_ear_exploded/officeApplication.jar#OfficeApplicationDS'
03:39:20,991 INFO  [org.jboss.as.jpa] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 25) WFLYJPA0011: Stopping Persistence Unit (phase 2 of 2) Service 'officeApplication_ear_exploded/officeApplication.war#OfficeApplicationPU'
03:39:20,991 INFO  [org.hibernate.orm.beans] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 25) HHH10005004: Stopping BeanContainer : org.hibernate.resource.beans.container.internal.CdiBeanContainerExtendedAccessImpl@27593d9a
03:39:20,991 INFO  [org.jboss.as.jpa] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 25) WFLYJPA0011: Stopping Persistence Unit (phase 1 of 2) Service 'officeApplication_ear_exploded/officeApplication.war#OfficeApplicationPU'
03:39:20,993 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-2) WFLYSRV0208: Stopped subdeployment (runtime-name: officeApplication.jar) in 2ms
03:39:21,006 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-8) WFLYSRV0208: Stopped subdeployment (runtime-name: officeApplication.war) in 16ms
03:39:21,006 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-8) WFLYSRV0028: Stopped deployment officeApplication_ear_exploded (runtime-name: officeApplication_ear_exploded.ear) in 16ms
[2021-11-13 03:39:21,025] Artifact officeApplication:ear exploded: Error during artifact deployment. See server log for details.
[2021-11-13 03:39:21,025] Artifact officeApplication:ear exploded: java.lang.Exception: {"WFLYCTL0080: Failed services" => {"jboss.persistenceunit.\"officeApplication_ear_exploded/officeApplication.jar#OfficeApplicationDS\"" => "org.hibernate.AnnotationException: Unable to create index (worker_idworker) on table worker_has_role: database column 'worker_idworker' not found. Make sure that you use the correct column name which depends on the naming strategy in use (it may not be the same as the property name in the entity, especially for relational types)
    Caused by: org.hibernate.AnnotationException: Unable to create index (worker_idworker) on table worker_has_role: database column 'worker_idworker' not found. Make sure that you use the correct column name which depends on the naming strategy in use (it may not be the same as the property name in the entity, especially for relational types)"}}
```

The class that makes error (I will also paste Worker Class just in case)

```
package ejbmodule.entities;

import javax.persistence.*;

@Table(name = "worker_has_role", indexes = {
        @Index(name = "fk_worker_has_role_role1_idx", columnList = "role_idrole"),
        @Index(name = "fk_worker_has_role_worker1_idx", columnList = "worker_idworker")
})
@Entity
public class WorkerHasRole {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "idworker_has_role", nullable = false)
    private Integer id;

    @ManyToOne(optional = false)
    @JoinColumn(name = "role_idrole", nullable = false)
    private Role roleIdrole;

    @ManyToOne(optional = false)
    private Worker workerIdworker;

    public Worker getWorkerIdworker() {
        return workerIdworker;
    }

    public void setWorkerIdworker(Worker workerIdworker) {
        this.workerIdworker = workerIdworker;
    }

    public Role getRoleIdrole() {
        return roleIdrole;
    }

    public void setRoleIdrole(Role roleIdrole) {
        this.roleIdrole = roleIdrole;
    }

    public Integer getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Integer id) {
        this.id = id;
    }
}
```

persistence.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<persistence xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence"
             xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
             xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_2.xsd"
             version="2.2">
    <persistence-unit name="OfficeApplicationDS" transaction-type="JTA">
        <class>ejbmodule.entities.Department</class>
        <class>ejbmodule.entities.Position</class>
        <class>ejbmodule.entities.WorkerId</class>
        <class>ejbmodule.entities.Worker</class>
        <class>ejbmodule.entities.Role</class>
        <class>ejbmodule.entities.WorkerHasRole</class>
        <jta-data-source>java:jboss/datasources/OfficeApplicationDS</jta-data-source>
        <exclude-unlisted-classes>false</exclude-unlisted-classes>
    </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

pom.xml of ejb

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.example</groupId>
        <artifactId>officeApplication</artifactId>
        <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </parent>

    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>ejbmodule</groupId>
    <artifactId>officeApplication_EJB</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>officeApplication_EJB</name>
    <packaging>ejb</packaging>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>
        <maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
        <junit.version>5.7.1</junit.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax</groupId>
            <artifactId>javaee-web-api</artifactId>
            <version>8.0.1</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.ejb</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.ejb-api</artifactId>
            <version>3.2.2</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
            <version>5.5.3.Final</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit-jupiter-api</artifactId>
            <version>${junit.version}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit-jupiter-engine</artifactId>
            <version>${junit.version}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <version>8.0.27</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.3.1</version>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

Worker class just in case

```
package ejbmodule.entities;

import javax.persistence.*;

@Table(name = "workers", indexes = {
        @Index(name = "fk_worker_department1_idx", columnList = "department_iddepartment"),
        @Index(name = "fk_worker_position1_idx", columnList = "position_idposition")
})
@Entity
public class Worker {
    @EmbeddedId
    private WorkerId id;

    @Column(name = "name_worker", nullable = false, length = 45)
    private String nameWorker;

    @Column(name = "surname_worker", nullable = false, length = 45)
    private String surnameWorker;

    @Column(name = "phone_worker", nullable = false, length = 9)
    private String phoneWorker;

    @Column(name = "email_worker", nullable = false, length = 45)
    private String emailWorker;


    ..... list of many repetetive columns .....


    public WorkerId getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(WorkerId id) {
        this.id = id;
    }
}
```

hibernate.cfg.xml placed in project_EJB directory: main->resources->hibernate.cfg.xml

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration PUBLIC
    "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Configuration DTD//EN"
    "http://www.hibernate.org/dtd/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd">
<hibernate-configuration>
  <session-factory>
    <property name="connection.url">jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/officedb</property>
    <property name="connection.driver_class">com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver</property>
    <property name="connection.username">root</property>
    <property name="connection.password"></property>

    <!-- DB schema will be updated if needed -->
    <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">update</property>
  </session-factory>
</hibernate-configuration>
```

Comment: How does your database tables look like? The error messages is pretty clear. There is no column worker_idworker

Comment: Thanks for reply!. Uploaded database diagram, it is right before error log. I am sure the column is there. Similar application works with that database containing only automated generated entities from DB, but in this project I can't understand the problem.

Comment: And you are 100% sure that this shows the database that Hibernate is accessing?

Comment: Configuration is made in hibernate.cfg.xml in project_EJB directory as follows:
main->resources->hibernate.cfg.xml
I updated post with code from .xml at the end of the post.

Comment: Generated Entity WorkerHasRole from DB once again and it generated the same code, but without 
indexes = {
        @Index(name = "fk_worker_has_role_role1_idx", columnList = "role_idrole"),
        @Index(name = "fk_worker_has_role_worker1_idx", columnList = "worker_idworker")

Not sure whether it's correct with associative table, but it compiles fine...